# Finite-dimensional irreducible representations

Tags: functional-analysis

How do we show that a finite-dimensional $*$-representation of a $C^{*}$-algebra is unitary equivalent to a direct sum of irreducible representations?

Comment: Take orthogonal complements.

Answer (score 1):

If $M$ is a finite dimensional representation of a $C^*$ algebra $A$, then it is in fact a representation of a quotient $B=A/I$ by a closed ideal of finite codimension.

So you may just as well assume that $A$ is finite-dimensional. Then it is a direct product of matrix algebras, and it is therefore semisimple.

What you want follows at once from this.